# How to access different data type element in a list?

Tags: python

I have table varchar column with values, I'm trying to create & access list element in Python for data cleaning. I have list ( Column sample values) like this:

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance',1,2,3,'Fire Crew',1,2]
```

i.e Ambulance followed by "1, 2, 3" means ambulance was contacted 3 times and 
Fire Crew followed by "1 2" means Fire Crew was contacted 2 times. 
So finally I need to produce a list which contains this, before loading into target table

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance','Ambulance','Ambulance','Fire Crew','Fire Crew']
```

I need to produce Reports saying 3 calls for Ambulance Department, 2 calls for Fire Crew Department etc.

I have the static implementation using JavaScript.

```
var n = Caller_ID;
var len = n.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (n.indexOf('Ambulance') > -1) {
    var nn = n[i + 1] = 'Ambulance';
  } else if (n.indexOf('Fire Crew') > -1) {
    nn = n[i + 1] = 'Fire Crew';`
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance','Ambulance','Ambulance','Ambulance','Fire Crew','Fire Crew','Fire Crew','Police','Police']
```

I'm looking for the dynamic implementation using Python.

For this input:

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance',1,2,3,'Fire Crew',1,2,'Policia',1]
```

I need this output:

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance','Ambulance','Ambulance','Fire Crew','Fire Crew','Policia']
```

Comment: Why not converting the datatype to a dictionary that the value will be the counter and the key will be the service/item?

Comment: Where do you get the list from? It's quite an impractical data structure for this problem. Just having `Caller_ID = ['Ambulance',3,'Fire Crew',2,'Police',1]` would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Have you tried anything in Python?

Comment: What is `'Fire Crew', Fire Crew` supposed to mean? The first is a string, but what is the latter? Doesn't look like Python syntax.

Comment: Does that JavaScript code even work?  It looks to me like it'll just set every element of the list to "Ambulance".

Comment: @jwodder, JS is working when I hard code the Ambulance & Fire Crew values.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using `itertools.groupby` to group the integers together and separate them from the strings. The "trick" is to use `type` as the `groupby` key function.

```
from itertools import groupby

Caller_ID = ['Ambulance', 1, 2, 3, 'Fire Crew', 1, 2, 'Police', 1]

newlist = []
for k, g in groupby(Caller_ID, key=type):
    g = list(g)
    if k is str:
        s = g
    else:
        newlist.extend(s * len(g))

print(newlist)
```

**output**

```
['Ambulance', 'Ambulance', 'Ambulance', 'Fire Crew', 'Fire Crew', 'Police']
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, no imports needed, just an easy and clear-to-read for loop.

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance',1,2,3,'Fire Crew',1,2]

new_list = []
for item in Caller_ID:
    if type(item) == str:
        current = item
    else:
        new_list.append(current)

>>> new_list
['Ambulance', 'Ambulance', 'Ambulance', 'Fire Crew', 'Fire Crew']
```

Comment: There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pick both strings and counts as you go through the list:

```
Caller_ID = ['Ambulance',1,2,3,'Fire Crew',1,2,'Police',1]
Callers = []  # list to hold result
current_caller, caller_count = "", 0  # temporary variables holding current element
# iterate through the list, pick each name and count
for elem in Caller_ID:
    # new name found
    if isinstance(elem, str):  # in python2.X, use basestring
        Callers.extend([elem] * caller_count)  # store last name with appropriate count
        current_caller, caller_count = elem, 0  # reset state
    else:
        caller_count += 1
Callers.extend([current_caller] * caller_count)
```

`Callers` will contain the items you are looking for. Note that this assumes that names are not repeated, or that in this case the relative position and count is required.